# Quitting the iPhone Simulator does not actually stop my program, why?

Tags: ios4, xcode4, ios-simulator

If I do the following:

1. Open and run my app for a while in the iPhone Simulator.
2. Then send my app to the background by pressing the center button on the iPhone.
3. Then Quit the iPhone Simulator

My program does not stop.  It displays Thread 1 saying it's in main.  It does not give a SIGTERM or anything like that.  There is no highlight of any line of code in main.  It simply hangs there displaying Thread 1.  Then I have to press the Stop button to stop it.

Does anyone know why it would do this?  If I skip step 2 then it works fine and stops my program normally.  Thx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking at the debugger, you will see:

sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
(gdb)

This is printed after following the steps you supplied. The debugger log is normal behavior. It show that xCode has been informed the app stopped running. xCode for some strange reason just doesn't update the UI.